# How to send checked box information to my email inbox along with the form information I'm already getting using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

So with what I currently have set up, I'm able to successfully send information to my email inbox using php. The problem is I'm only able to send the information entered in a text form, such as contactName, contactEmail, contactPhone, and contactMessage, but I'm not able to send any information associated with checked boxes. I want to be able to send the value or name of each checked box to my email inbox along with the rest pf the information I'm currently getting.

This is my php. There is actually a lot more check boxes, but I removed all but one for simplicity. I'm basically trying to add each checkbox name to the $message being sent to my inbox, but for some reason none of the checkbox information is being added to the message:

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['contactName'])){

  $contactName = $_REQUEST['contactName'];
  $contactEmail = $_REQUEST['contactEmail'];
  $contactPhone = $_REQUEST['contactPhone'];
  $contactMessage = $_REQUEST['contactMessage'];

  $subject = "Information Request from " . $contactName;
  $comment = "Additional Comments: " . $contactMessage;

  $message = $contactName . "\n Phone Number: " . $contactPhone .
        "\n Email address: " . $contactEmail .
        "\n Additional Comments: " . $contactMessage . "\n\n" .
            ' has requested information on the following items:' . "\n\n";

   if( isset($_REQUEST['gateway_or_hub'] ) )$message .= "gateway_or_hub\n";

  $to = 'myName <myName@email.com>';
  $add_headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email .'>' . "\r\n";

  if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$add_headers) == TRUE){
    output_form_header_completed();
  } else {
      output_form_header_incompleted();
    }
} else {
    output_form();
}

?>
```

Here is my HTML with removed formatting for one of my check boxes:

```
<form name="products_form" id="products_form" action="./products.php" method="post">

  <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox" for="gateway_or_hub">
    <input type="checkbox" id="gateway_or_hub" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">HUB</span>
  </label>
```

Here is my HTML submit button:

```
<button name="productsSubmit" id="productsSubmit" type="submit">SEND REQUEST</button>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(function() {
});

$( "#productsClear" ).click(function() {

  $('#contactErrorMessage').hide();

  $('#contactName').text('');
  $('#contactPhone').text('');
  $('#contactEmail').text('');
  $('#contactMessage').text('');
});

$( "#productsSubmit" ).click(function() {

  $('#contactErrorMessage').hide();

  // Check Name
  var input=$('#contactName');
  var is_name=input.val();
  if(! is_name){
    $('#contactErrorMessage').show();
    $('#contactErrorMessage').text("Valid Name is requierd!")
    return;
  }

  // Check Email
  var input=$('#contactEmail');
  var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    var is_email=re.test(input.val());
  if(! is_email){
    $('#contactErrorMessage').show();
    $('#contactErrorMessage').text("Valid email is requierd!")
    return;
  }

  console.log("Form should submit!");
  $("#products_form").submit();
});
```

Comment: No `name` attribute in `checkbox`.

Comment: Thank you Nana! I can't believe I missed that. Hopefully this will help others who may miss it themselves in the future.

Comment: Glad to point it out.